# Simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in Javascript (NO A.I.)

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

After some hours of coding trying to implement "algorithms" to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game, I came up with something I'm not really proud of.

Here's the code:

```
const TicTacToe = (function(){

    const grids = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    const winning_combinations = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    let turn = 'X';
    let marks = 0;
    let currPos = void 0;

    for(let i = 0, len = grids.length; i < len; ++i)
        grids[i].addEventListener("click", () => mark( (currPos=i) )  );

    function mark(pos){
        if(grids[currPos].textContent != '')
            return alert("grid taken!");

        grids[currPos].textContent = turn;

        if(!foundWinner())
            turn = (turn === 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
        else
            win();

    }   

    function foundWinner(){

        for(let currSet = 0, len = winning_combinations.length; currSet < len; ++currSet){

            winning_combinations[currSet].forEach(pos => {
                if(grids[pos].textContent == turn){
                    marks++;
                }               
            });

            if(marks == 3){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                marks = 0;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    function win(){
        return alert(turn + " won!");
    }

    return{
        reset: function(){
            // todo
        }
    }

}) ();
```

The issue is that I am pretty sure this code has `O(n log n)` time complexity, and I would love to make it at least `O(n)`. I've tried creating possible combinations based on what grid the player pressed—opposed to trying all the winning combinations—but no avail.

If there is any way I can better this code or make it more efficient, please let me know!

Comment: Computational complexity is *usually* only something to worry about when you have inputs of significant sizes. If you have a static 3x3 grid with a static 8 possible winning positions to iterate over, I don't see what a theoretical bottleneck could be; those numbers are very small. (unless something is auto-clicking and restarting games in a very tight loop, which sounds like it isn't the case)

Comment: Can you clarify the sort of performance improvements you're looking for?